# Synchronizing state access between OnNavigatedTo and OnNavigatedFrom

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, asynchronous, windows-runtime, win-universal-app

My application has two pages, which we will call TheMenu and TheForm. When the user leaves TheForm and returns to TheMenu, `TheForm.OnNavigatedFrom()` will save state to isolated storage, and `TheMenu.OnNavigatedTo()` will read some of that state from the isolated storage to re-initialize TheMenu.

The problem is that since storage access is asynchronous, `TheMenu.NavigatedTo()` will begin reading state before `TheForm.OnNavigatedFrom()` has finished writing it.

I'm thinking of handling this by creating application-wide instance of `AsyncLock` (implementation provided here: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ComparingTwoTechniquesInNETAsynchronousCoordinationPrimitives.aspx). I would acquire the lock at the top of `OnNavigatedTo()`, and release it from a `finally {}` block at the bottom of `OnNavigatedFrom()`.

Does anyone foresee any issues with this approach? Is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 1):

Although it is good practice to write state out to disk at appropriate intervals, for something like this you should use an in-memory representation rather than round-tripping via the disk. There are many ways to design it, but one common approach is to have a static property off your `App` class that holds the shared state. You can save it to disk when navigating away from pages (as you already do) but when you navigate to a page, first check if there is a valid object stored in the `App`'s property before trying to read from disk.